# TypeScript: Create an union type of strings from a certain type

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type `IconName` that looks like this:

```js
type IconName = 'cars' | 'mars' | 'truck' | 'warning'
```

I want then to create another type `VehicleIconName` which contains all icons name related to a vehicle:

```js
type VehicleIconName = 'cars' | 'truck'
```

But how can I tell to TypeScript that each strings in `VehicleIconName` have to be of type `IconName` too?

So that I couldn't write this:

```js
type VehicleIconName = 'cars' | 'truck' | 'invalidIconName'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a helper type:

```
type Subset<Parent, Sub extends Parent> = Extract<Parent, Sub>;

type IconName = 'cars' | 'mars' | 'truck' | 'warning'

type VehicleIconName = Subset<IconName, 'cars' | 'truck' | 'invalidName'>
```

Error on last line:

> Type '"cars" | "truck" | "invalidName"' does not satisfy the constraint 'IconName'.
>   Type '"invalidName"' is not assignable to type 'IconName'.ts(2344)

Comment: Yep works like a charm  Do you think it's the only way to achieve this?

Comment: @johannchopin: Maybe; at the very least i could not think of another method.

Comment: You could improve the `Subset` type by having it equal to `Extract<Parent, Sub>` instead of just `Sub`. Otherwise although the definition of `VehicleIconName` throws an error, `const x: VehicleIconName = "invalidName"` would still be a valid assignment.

Comment: @ftm: Probably a good idea to report those errors right away, thanks for the suggestion.